# If then statement involving sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let S be a universe of discourse, with subsets $A, B{\subseteq } S$ . Show If     $ A^c{\subseteq}B$ then $A{\cup}B = S$

I'm really confused here. Must I show both inclusions are true in the "then statement" to prove this proof? Here is my proof:

If $x {\in}  A^c$ then $x {\in} B$. Since $A{\cup} A^c=S$ we have that $A{\cup}B = S$.

Answer (score 0):

You should assume that $A^c \subseteq B$ and use this information to show that $A \cup B = S$

Your proof, then slightly reworded, would be correct.

Suppose $A^c \subseteq B$. Take $x \in S$. Then $x \in A$ or $x \in A^c \implies x \in B$. In either case, $x \in A \cup B$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, we have $A \cup B \supseteq S$. Since $A, B \subseteq S$ we have $A \cup B = S$.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to show that $A \cup B = S$ so you need to prove that these are subsets of one another.

The fact that $A \cup B \subseteq S$ is obvious since $S$ is the universe so both $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $S$.

To show the other inclusion let $x \in S$. Then either $x \in A$ or $x \in A^c$. If $x \in A$ you are done since $x \in A\cup B$. If $x \in A^c$ then $x \in B$ (which is what you noted in your working) and again $x \in A \cup B$. This shows $S \subseteq A \cup B$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now to the next example Im trying to prove $B^c{\subseteq}A^c$ using $A{\subseteq}B$. Any tips? Here is my proof: Let $x {\in} B^c$  then $x{\in} A  and  x{\notin}B$. We know that if $x{\in} A$ we have that $x{\in}B $ hence $x{\in}A^c$

Comment: Almost, but $x \in B^c$ doesn't imply that $x \in A$. If it did, then your result would be nonsense, because you have at one point said $x \in A$ and then later concluded $x \in A^c$. Also, I think you could use an extra bit of explanation before your conclusion. $\textit{Why}$ can you conclude the result from what you said. Something like, "Let $x \in B^c$ then $x \notin B$. But we know that $x \in A \implies x \in B$, therefore since $x \notin B$ we have that $x \notin A$ (contrapositive of $A \subseteq B$). Hence . . ."

Answer (score 0):

$S = A{\cup}A^c \subseteq A{\cup}B \subseteq S.$